# How to retrieve child records for fields of study in MAKG using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, knowledge-graph

I am currently working with the Microsoft Academic Knowledge Graph (MAKG) dataset, specifically using the RDF schema provided at https://makg.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/mag-rdf-schema-2021-03-2.png. I am querying the dataset using SPARQL through the MAKG SPARQL endpoint at https://makg.org/sparql-endpoint/.

My goal is to obtain a list of all fields of study along with their child records. The dataset indicates that there are 740,460 fields of study, but when I query the data, I only get the top-level fields without any child records.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?FieldOfStudy
WHERE {
  [] a ?FieldOfStudy
}
LIMIT 100
```

Could you please guide me on how to construct a SPARQL query to retrieve the child records for each field of study?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: the shown query returns all types in the dataset, but **not** the fields of study. Gettings all fields of study would be `SELECT ?s
WHERE {
  ?s a <https://makg.org/class/FieldOfStudy>
}` - but I'm not sufre what exactly you're aksing for

Answer (score 0):

The triple pattern `[] a ?FieldOfStudy` finds triples

- with any subject,
- with the property `rdf:type`, and
- with ***any*** object, because you didn’t bind that variable to something.

If you want to only find triples with the class `https://makg.org/class/FieldOfStudy` as object, you could specify this IRI directly. Note that the actual study fields would be the subjects in the triples, so it makes sense to use your variable `?FieldOfStudy` in the subject position.

```
PREFIX magc: <https://makg.org/class/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?FieldOfStudy
WHERE {
  ?FieldOfStudy a magc:FieldOfStudy . 
}
LIMIT 10
```

You can count the results to verify that it finds 740460:

```
PREFIX magc: <https://makg.org/class/>

SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT ?FieldOfStudy) AS ?count)
WHERE {
  ?FieldOfStudy a magc:FieldOfStudy . 
}
```